# checkboxes list panel show when clicking dropdown list in MVC 3.0 razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to create a checkbox list inside a dropdown list.I want user to be able to do multi-select of items .I want to show the items in a dropdown list with a check box adjacent to each item to make a selection.Is there a way to do this?.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done using a standard dropdown list, but you can do it by creating your own custom dropdown structure. 
It's a bit too much to cover in this answer, but some ideas are:

A z-indexed slidable panel that you can collapse and expand. The z-index is needed to ensure that the dropdown floats on top of its section.
You can put whatever markup you want in the panel, including a list of checkboxes.

Comment: It can be created as a div. Use absolute/relative positioning to be able to use z-index. I would start by looking up the basics on how to do that. You can use Jquery's hide and show to expand and collapse the panel.

Answer (score 0):

[This jquery widget](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/) by Eric Hynds works great for what you're trying to do.